# Angular2 node_module rxjs 404 error

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

I am trying to compile an angular2 app but I get the following error:

> Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs(…)

**systemjs.config.js**

```
(function(global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': {
            main: 'main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'rxjs': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'forms',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated',
        'upgrade',
    ];

    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        };
    }

    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = {
            main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        };
    }

    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };
    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

The app folder contains: `main.ts` and `YouTubeSearchComponent.ts`

What may cause this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your rxjs entry in package to this:

```
'rxjs': {
    main: '/bundles/Rx.umd.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this compile without errors, why i should set the mail directive? please explain it to me

Comment: Thats main config, to tell systemjs the main file to be picked up.  Check node_modules/rxjs you will find bundles/Rx.umd.js

Comment: You are correct Siraj, need to specify file name for rxjs too.